# Using an empty <div> to fill up menu bar space

Tags: html, css

In [this](http://shapebootstrap.net/item/1524962-corlate-free-responsive-business-html-template/live-demo) website, top side of the picture is consumed by the black menu bar. I would like to place an empty `<div>` to push the picture downwards. `<div>` height needs to be resized automatically to prevent blank space from appearing in different resolutions.

I tried adding empty `<div>`s, using vmin/vmax, didn't work.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wrtozrLp/1/)

menu bar

```html
        <header id="header">
        <div class="top-bar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                </div>
            </div><!--/.container-->
        </div><!--/.top-bar-->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                </div>
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                </div>
            </div><!--/.container-->
        </nav><!--/nav-->
    </header><!--/header-->
```

Comment: I expect we won't need the full menu bar contents to help you out with this. Can you cut the html down to the simplest version, and also provide the minimal css?

Comment: "Empty" divs for spacing are not a good idea. There are much better options using padding or margins. Altenatively, look into `calc` or `flexbox`.

Comment: You might be able to use `margin-top`, or `padding-top` instead of an empty div. But it also sounds like you probably have `header {position: fixed}` or `position: absolute` - if so, try taking that out and the picture should follow the header with no overlap

Comment: I removed some unnecessary parts of html. I will try your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Empty divs is not a necessity, I thought it would be the only solution, apparently I was wrong.

Comment: I had to use `{position: fixed}` to keep menu bar on top. How can I figure out header's height in different resolutions?

Comment: Fork this and add it you your question so people can see it in action and play with the code. :-) http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/wrtozrLp/

Comment: Is there a way to start (or position) the div that contains the image where the header ends? What is the reason for header to overlap the picture while all other sections follow each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is used as 'background-image' on a div with a fixed size. Some advantages are loading time and that the image can not be selected or dragged. A disadvantages the inflexibility. It's not that the black bar overlaps the image, as you can see when inspecting the element, but it's the div itself that cuts off part of the image. The best thing you can do is only use header images that exactly fit the container or you can play with the CSS `background-size`. Have a look at `cover`, but know that `cover` does not work in older browsers.